# Change variable from usestate other variable is getting reset in functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

When I'm updating my state variable, so my state variable is changed, but my all other variables are getting resting to their initial values. I am adding my test component.

If I remove **setTest** so my **combileFileData** gives value as expected after pressing add button, but when I use **setTest** so everytime it gives me ['b]

```
  const [pass, setPass] = React.useState([]);
  let combineFileData = ["b"];

  function showHandler() {
    console.log("combine file data", combineFileData);
  }

  function addHandler() {
    setPass(["a", "s"]);

    combineFileData.push("a");
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={showHandler}>Show</button>
      <button onClick={addHandler}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Changing the state causes the component to re-render. `let combineFileData = ["b"];` is called everytime the component renders. So everytime you set the state, `combineFileData` becomes `b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `combineFileData` is “reinitialized” on every render. There fore it behaves like it has its initial value always.

To keep your inplementation as much same as possible you can use ref like this:

```js
const combineFileData = useRef([“b”]);

function addHandler() {
    setPass(["a", "s"]);

    combineFileData.current.push("a");
}
```